# Why is one project dependency replaced by another already existing one

Tags: gradle

My build is failing because some dependencies are not met. When I run the gradle dependencies task I get something surprising. The completely different projects project :state:api and the project :bus:api are not treated differently but as the same. Whis seems to be the reason why I only get the bus api's classes onto my classpath. But why? I am using gradle 4.7, I have also tried settings.gradle with rootProject.name on various places without any difference.

```
./gradlew server:dependencies --configuration compile | grep project
+--- project :bus:api
+--- project :bus:simple-list-bus
|    +--- project :bus:api
+--- project :state:api -> project :bus:api
+--- project :state:simple-state
|    +--- project :state:api -> project :bus:api
+--- project :utils:common
```

bus/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

bus/api/build.gradle

```
group 'kic'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
archivesBaseName = 'kic-bus-api'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

state/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

state/api/build.gradle

```
group 'kic'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
archivesBaseName = 'kic-state-api'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like the rootProject.name in the settings.gradle is not respected anymore. It very much looks like there is now only one (the top root) settings.gradle respected/allowed. This means one has to specify the submodule names in the most top root settings.gradle like so:

```
include ':bus'
include ':bus:api'
include ':bus:simple-list-bus'
include ':state'
include ':state:api'
include ':state:simple-state'

project(":state:api").name = "kic-state-api"
project(":state:simple-state").name = "kic-state-simple"
project(":bus:api").name = "kic-bus-api"
project(":bus:simple-list-bus").name = "kic-bus-simple"
```